# Не удаётся скомпилировать Hello World при помощи masm32

Tags: ассемблер

Написал такой код (файл назвал hello.asm):

```
global _main
extern _printf
section .text
_main:
push message
call _printf
add esp, 4
ret
message:
db 'Hello, World', 10, 0
```

Но выдает ошибки и сообщение `must be in segments block`

Как их решить?

Система: windows 7, 32 битная архитектура.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая команда используется для компиляции? Укажите, пожалуйста, полную строку компиляции

Comment: Для компиляции используется такая команда: `C:\masm32\bin> ml.exe hello.asm`

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете для компиляции MASM (Macro Assembler от Microsoft), однако код написан в синтаксисе для другого ассемблера (вообще говоря, синтаксисов много разных). В частности, ровно такой синтаксис использует [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/). После установки NASM вы сможете скомпилировать свой код двумя командами:

```
nasm -f win32 hello.asm
link hello.obj msvcrt.lib
```